# How do I access request parameters in kademi templates?

Tags: html, templates, velocity, kademi

I've been developing a website with Kademi and i'm trying to implement a date range search, I've got the date range adding parameters to the URL

```
?startDate=02/05/15&endDate=12/12/2015
```

But I don't know how to retrieve these values in kademi templates.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Kademi templating guide[1], there is a request object in context for template rendering. The request object has a params property which is a map of parameter names and values.

So you can do this:

```
 $request.params.startDate
```

Note that this returns a string. If you want to convert it to a Date object use the formatter:

```
$formatter.toDate( $request.params.startDate )
```

[1] http://docs.kademi.co/ref/guides/1-templating-overview.html